# state is cleared, but input field text is not after form is submitted in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am doing exercise on a simple todo App, the user can type their todos in the  field, and hit submit to see it added to the todo-list.

I've managed to clear the state once the form is submitted with 'this.setState({newTodo: ''})' (indicated by hitting submit again will add an empty todo-item);

however, the text in the input field will not be cleared.

```
const TodoItem = ({ text }) => <li>{text}</li>;

class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        todos: ['walk dog', 'feed cat'],
        newTodo: ''
};

this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const todos = [...this.state.todos, this.state.newTodo];

    this.setState({ todos, newTodo: '' });
}

render() {
    const { newTodo } = this.state; 
    const todos = this.state.todos.map((todo, index) => <TodoItem key={index} text={todo} />);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <h1>Simple Todo App</h1>

                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="newTodo"
                    value={this.newTodo}

                    onChange={e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })}
                />

                <ol>
                  {todos}
                </ol>
                <button>SAVE</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default App;
```

Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: Change input field value attribute to value={newTodo}. Dont use this.newTodo.

Comment: @HemadriDasari Thanks a lot that solved the problem!

Comment: Just changing value={newTodo} resolved your issue? I don’t think so because you are passing empty newTodo state to todos array in handleSubmit and that will create empty todo-item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.newTodo` is undefined, use `this.state.newTodo` instead od `this.newTodo` :

```
<input
     type="text"
     name="newTodo"
     value={this.state.newTodo} 
      onChange={e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })}
/>
```

OR:

```
const { newTodo } = this.state; 
<input
     type="text"
     name="newTodo"
     value={newTodo} 
      onChange={e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I just realized newTodo never existed as an individual prop except inside this.state. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see empty newTodo added because your newTodo initial state is empty and in handleSubmit you are always passing it irrespective of whether it’s is empty or not. So In handleSubmit check newTodo state and then add newTodo to todos array.

```
 if(this.state.newTodo != “”){
      const todos = [...this.state.todos, this.state.newTodo];
 }
```

and change input field value attribute value to newTodo

```
 <input value={newTodo} />
```

Don’t use this.newTodo

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I actually just realized newTodo exists only in this.state, rather than a property on the class App. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the following section:

```
<input
 type="text"
 name="newTodo"
 value={this.newTodo}
 onChange={e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })}
/>
```

Change `value={this.newTodo}` to `value={this.state.newTodo}`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I actually just realized newTodo exists only in this.state, rather than a property on the class App. Thanks!